# CSS image height with strange behavior

Tags: html, css

I have a picture and a form side-by-side but I'm not being able to achieve the desired effect. This is what it initially looks like:

[image]

Which is cool, but the picture is way to big. The picture contained can vary, so a fixed width *and* height is not an option, because it would deform the image. I would like to give it a height property and let it adjust the width accordingly. This is what I get if I do that:

[image]

I don't understand why the image is aligning to the bottom... The chrome metrics show nothing in that space. No padding, no margin, nothing. I cannot use negative margins because resizing the browser window causes the layout to respond and the image is thrown out of the window. This is what it looks like with a margin-top of -270px (this is exactly what I want).

[image]

But if I resize this is what happens.

[image]

Here's an HTML snippet. Please tell me if you need more code:

```
<div class="well second-step">
    <div>
        <div><img class="img-polaroid"></div>
        <div style="">
            <form id="{{ form.auto_id|pyformat:'form' }}" class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'look-creation-view' %}" method="POST">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Look's title">
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
                    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancel">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Publish">
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="image">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

I created a bootply, and I just added code until the issue replicated. I hope it's enough. Here it is: http://bootply.com/76022

Comment: Can you add a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: your CSS please. I feel this could be an issue due to `vertical-align`.

Comment: I cannot see any images :( Could you please make a fiddle for the same?

Comment: Since you're using Bootstrap, make a [Bootply](http://bootply.com/new)

Comment: Try adding `float: left;` to the div containing the img (or `class='pull-left'` since you're using bootstrap)

Comment: I'll try creating a Bootply!

Comment: Just edited the question!

Comment: If I use float: left; the .well behind does not adjust to the content's size

Comment: @AndréFratelli: Did your problem get solved? If not, have a look at this [**link**](http://bootply.com/76107). Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: It's perfect !!! How could it have been so simple? :D thank you so much !! Could you post as an answer so I could accept it? Thank you again !! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You might consider this:

**First step:** using a div with a width and height:

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

Than apply CSS

```
.div {
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
}
```

**Step two:** Wrap the image in it as:

```
<div class="image"><img src="~/folder/file.png" alt="photo: /></div>
```

Try to apply the css

```
.image img {
width: 100%;
heighti: 100%;
}
```

This CSS will make it get the height and width according to the div. The div has 500px width so the width will never be more than that.

**Third step:**

Now to make sure it stays at the top left use this:

```
.image img {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

The third step means that the image should have 0 margin from left and top.

Comment: It's a lot better! But it still deforms the images =(

Comment: Are you using the percentage? If you are using the percentage, then the image should never walk out. You might also consider using this: `.image {border: 1px solid #333}`to check what is the div size to this width. So that the image should always stay in the limit. After that the width and height will be applied. Making it sure that the image stays in the boundary. And the position property will make sure that the image is always on the top left side.

Comment: Yes, I used percentage! The image does not stay exactly in the limit because it has padding, but I think that's OK. Everything seems fine, except the image distortion. See here, the image should be squared like in my initial post: http://oi40.tinypic.com/npl9g9.jpg

Comment: Then the error was nothing else, then the width and height. The width and height of a square are same, we are not using same value! Use 500px for both. That will fix it.

Comment: Btw, I also added a position: relative; to the div containing the picture. Otherwise the image would position relatively to the window.

Comment: Yes I have seen the image. The issue is the width and height.

Comment: If you use something like `.image {width: 500px; height: 500px}` that will fix the error.

Comment: It doesn't. The image is taking 100% of the size, so now rectangular images deform...

Comment: So you want to change the image dimensions?

Comment: I changed width: 100%; and height: 100%; to max-width: 100%; and max-height: 100%; It's bettern but here's what I get http://oi43.tinypic.com/6ftau9.jpg

Comment: This will always override. You need to change the dimensions, so please use my code! Also, try to learn a image.resize() are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: What you want to achieve can never be done like this. You need some server side coding that will crop the image or just change its dimensions, but believe me thats hell. That will crop the image, but at the same time it will mess you image. pixels will be messed. So try to get the image with this. Your users will never appreciate that feature unless they want it.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using your code. The images are already resized, I'm using django!

Comment: Crop? o.O All I want is the image with a max-width: 300px; and whichever height matches that, side-by-side with a form. Are you saying it can't be done?

Comment: What I mean is the code I provided will help you resize the image I mean zoom it, not to change the dimensions of the real image. You can change the rect image in a square but that won't look pretty. Use px instead of % then.

Comment: Then use what I said: You can change the code too to meet your requirements. `.image {width: 300px; // height not specified}` for image use `.image img { width: 100%; height: 100%}`. This is all.

Comment: All images are resized to 800x600 (max, keeping ratio) in the server. I tried that last suggestion, this is what I get: http://oi41.tinypic.com/2vdpsig.jpg Two days lost with something like this !! -.-;

Comment: Have you seen the fiddle I added to the question? Could you please give a look? =\

Comment: What you fiddle is suggesting and what you image (the one in the recent comment of yours) does is almost opposite. The issue in your image (comment) is that the absolute is positioning it above the form. And the fiddle is working find, but that might have the error of the width and height. However if all images are resized to 800x600. Then I guess there is no issue at all, you can simply use width: 500px by 500px for the div. If you want a square.

Comment: Afzaal, the fiddle represents the *initial* problem. The prints you see in this conversation apply to your suggestions! So, yes, they are differente things. If I use 500x500 for the div it works fine for squares, yes! But the images are not resized to 800x600, they are resized to *at most* 800x600, keeping ratio! That is, the final image could be 800x455, or 350x600. Only either width or height are guaranteed to have that size, not both. Thank you for everything !!

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute positioning to put it at the top of the containing div, like so:

```
<div class="well second-step">
    <div id="img-form-container">
        <div><img class="img-polaroid"></div>
        <div style="">
            <form id="{{ form.auto_id|pyformat:'form' }}" class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'look-creation-view' %}" method="POST">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Look's title">
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
                    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancel">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Publish">
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="image">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
img-form-container {
    position: relative;
};
img-polaroid {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px; //this can be changed to give it margin
};
```